# this with static field JAVA

Tags: java, static

Lets say I have next situation:

```
private static int a;
private int b;
public void setMethod(int a){
   //Do something with static a and parameter a for example 
   b = this.a + a;
}
```

How to reference static a in this calculation? I tried this.a but I have Idea warning(because static member is accessed via reference which is wrong). Of course there is a way to rename parameter or static member but I don't want that if I am not forced.

Comment: Use `ClassName.a`.

Comment: static member should be assessed with ClassName....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access it using the class name:

```
public class Foo {
    private static int a;
    private int b;
    public void setMethod(int a){
       //Do something with static a and parameter a for example 
       b = Foo.a + a;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to protect you method if you are calling it concurrently.

Comment: Thank you, I came with this idea right after posting question. :) Just one question. What mean to protect my method?